# How can I delete files from low graphics mode?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, delete

Yesterday I was trying to recover some lost files from an external drive using r-linux. I think this filled my laptop's hard drive and my computer suddenly crashed and went into low graphics mode which doesn't let me log in at all.

I searched on here about low graphics mode and confirmed that full disk is one of the reasons.

Following the advice I managed to get to a VT and run the commands

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

But they didn't help. Then I managed to do the command

```
df -h
```

and this showed me a table, which shows I have no space.

That's where I am stuck, I can't out figure how to delete things. I tried the command

```
sudo du -kxa / | sort -nr | head
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I find the contents I want to delete and then how to actually select the big/not important ones and delete them through the commands?

`df -h` returns:

```
filesystem  size  used  avail  use%  Mounted on
dev/sda1    455gb 449g  0      100%  /
udev        2,0G  4,0K  2,0G   1%    /dev
tmpfs       806M   820K 805M   1%   /run
none        5,0M     0  5,0M   0%   /run/lock
none        2,0G     0  2,0G   0%   /run/shm
none        100M  8,0K  100M   1%   /run/user
overflow    1,0M  4,0K  1020K  1%   /tmp
```

Comment: Why is `sudo du -kxa / | sort -nr | head` not working? It must do something.

Comment: You can delete files from a terminal using the `rm` command. For more information execute `man rm`.

Comment: Please show us the output of `df -h`. Basically, you need to use `rm` to delete files but we can't tell you which ones unless you give us more details. The `sudo du -kxa / | sort -nr | head ` might not work if you have no space left. Try `sudo du -ch / | grep -P '^\d+G'` instead. That should give you a list of files/dirs whose size is in the gigabytes. They should serve as a starting point. Since there's no sorting, that is likely to run with no errors. Post the output here and we'll what we can do.

Comment: Hi. thank you for getting back to me. I am still stuck so let me try to copy what i see on the screen after I do the df -H
filesystem  size  used  avail  use%  Mounted on

Comment: sorry, I run out of time this is it 
Hi. thank you for getting back to me. I am still stuck so let me try to copy what i see on the screen after I do the df -H
filesystem  size  used  avail  use%  Mounted on
dev/sda1    455gb 449g  0       100%  /
udev             2,0G      4,0K  2,0G  1%      /dev
tmpfs            806M   820K 805M 1%   /run
none             5,0M     0          5,0M   0%  /run/lock
none             2,0G      0          2,0G    0%  /run/user
none             100M  8,0K    100M   1%  /run/user
overflow     1,0M    4,0K    1020K  1%  /tmp

Comment: is there a way I can post a picture from my screen here? 
I hand copied what I saw but the format is not correct... really sorry if it's adding difficulty to your effort to help me.. I am not very skilled but I hope you won't give up on me

Comment: You [edit] your question to provide additional information. This also has the advantage that you have no size limitations and that you can use the **`{}`**-code format button. Besides that, comments may be easily deleted without a notification.

Comment: I have now copied the table above, if anyone can offer any insights I will be xtremely appreciative. Everyone who has commented has been very helpful to me, but I still haven't managed to fix the problem.

Comment: @terdon I see you are from Athens. If you speak greek maybe you can help me, I'm greek and my laptop has greek ubuntu too, although now it speaks half english half greek. Anyways I don't mean to impose I just thought that might narrow the gap of my limited understanding of computer language.

Comment: @NancyK. sure, I created [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25032/room-for-terdon-and-nancy-k), come join me there.

Comment: @terdon can i contact you again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete some files. The best place to search is in your home directory. Most likely in your `~/Videos` folder. So, from the command line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd>) first run this:

```
cd ~/Videos
```

Then, look at what you have there. This command will show you the files ordered by size:

```
ls -lSr
```

Now, remove some of the bigger files:

```
rm "video file name.avi"
```

Once you have removed enough files, restart your computer and you can continue the cleanup using the GUI.

Comment: Thank you Terdon and everyone here! This solved the issue! I could never have done it without you! (now going to open a bottle of wine and celebrating my initiation in the amazing community of Ask Ubuntu!!)

Comment: are you around? prospathisa na sou steilo minima sto chat mas alla einai frozen. Psaxno texniko na me voithisei se kati kai ithela na rotiso esena, an mporeis @terdon

Comment: @NancyK. Sorry, holidays. I'm not at my computer and won't be for most of August. :(

Comment: kala na peraseis, sygnomi gia tin enoxlisi, tha vro texniko apo to internet, kales diakopes! @terdon